# Trouble accessing server.app.db within separate route files

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

My problem is: How can I access my `server.app.db` within my route files logic area?

I have put my routes into separate files, ie. user, country .. .
Each route file looks like this.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = [
  {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/user',
    config: {
      auth: 'simple',
      plugins: {'hapiAuthorization': {role: '...'}},
      handler: function (request, reply) {
        // Logic - I need server.app.db to connect to the database.
      }
    }
  }
  //.. more routes
];
```

In my server.js file I saved my database connection like this

```
server.app.db = databaseConnection;
```

If i try to access the server.app.db from the logic area within my route files my application just hangs.

The problem is not the database itself, i have connected to it without issues from the server.js file.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Yes it did, sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access object like this

```
request.server.app.db
```

The docs also explain the full properties of the request [object](http://hapijs.com/api#request-properties)